# How to keep webcam video centred when the height is 100% of the screen and the window is resized

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Using React I have a webcam video that must be centered at all times while the video's height is 100% of the screen height. I have the video filling the screen vertically fine but if I change the width of the window the video doesn't stay centered.

```
return (
  <div style={style.container}>
    <video style={style.video}
           ref={this.videoRef}
           autoPlay={true}></video>
  </div>
)

const style = {
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%', 
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  video: {
    transform: 'rotateY(180deg)',
    height: '100%',
    objectFit: 'contain',
    objectPosition: 'center'
  }
}
```

With the above, currently, the video just hugs the left of the window.

Comment: Try by adding `transform: 'rotateY(180deg) translateX(-50%)'` in video

Comment: This just pushes the video to the right side instead. Thanks though.

Comment: Can you show us an image of the current output

Answer (score 0):

If your video **width 100%**. Then you need to use **left:50%;** and **Margin-left:-50%;**
Hope It Helps?

Comment: `left:50%` will not work because video's `position` property is `static`

Comment: How mutch of your video width?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem and one of them is by adding

```
position: 'relative',
transform: 'rotateY(180deg) translateX(50%)',
left: '50%'
```

as following

```
const style = {
    container: {
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%', 
        overflow: 'hidden',
    },
    video: {
        position: 'relative',
        left: '50%',
        transform: 'rotateY(180deg) translateX(50%)',
        height: '100%',
        objectFit: 'contain',
        objectPosition: 'center'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using flexbox

```
const style = {
  container: {
    display: 'flex';
    alignItems: 'center';
    justifyContent: 'center';
    height: 'auto';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, it lead me to eventually what worked in the end which was:

```
const style = {
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%', 
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  video: {
    position: 'absolute',
    transform: 'rotateY(180deg)',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    left: '50%',
    marginLeft: '-50%',
    objectFit: 'cover',
    objectPosition: 'center'
  }
}
```